# Finding Cumulative Median In R Using Conditions

Tags: r, median

In my dataframe, how would I create a new variable with the median of Adv. (Advertising) amounts for each SIC group?

As an example:

```
SIC Adv.
1   65
1   96
1   NA
1   23
2   45
2   23
2   12
3   45
3   NA
3   35
3   6
3   888
4   23
5   656
5   547
6   12
6   32
6   1
```

Should become:

```
SIC Adv. SIC.Adv.Median
1   65  65
1   96  65
1   NA  65
1   23  65
2   45  23
2   23  23
2   12  23
3   45  40
3   NA  40
3   35  40
3   6   40
3   888 40
4   23  23
5   656 601.5
5   547 601.5
6   12  12
6   32  12
6   1   12
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `ave(df$Adv., df$SIC, FUN = function(x) median(x[!is.na(x)]))`

Comment: This worked! Thanks! How would I alter this to take into account two grouping variables (for example, median of Adv. based on SIC and Year)?

Comment: You are awesome! Worked perfectly.